# How to sort lines in textfile according to a second textfile

Tags: linux, sorting, vim, text, awk

I have two text files.

File A.txt:

```
john
peter
mary
alex
cloey
```

File B.txt

```
peter does something
cloey looks at him
franz is the new here
mary sleeps
```

I'd like to

- merge the two
- sort one file according to the other
- put the unknown lines of B at the end

like this:

```
john
peter does something
mary sleeps
alex
cloey looks at him
franz is the new here
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { b[$1]=$0; next }
    { print ($1 in b ? b[$1] : $1); delete b[$1] }
    END { for (i in b) print b[i] }
  ' fileB fileA
john
peter does something
mary sleeps
alex
cloey looks at him
franz is the new here
```

The above will print the remaining items from fileB in a "random" order (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array for details). If that's a problem then edit your question to clarify your requirements for the order those need to be printed in.

It also assumes the keys in each file are unique (e.g. `peter` only appears as a key value once in each file). If that's not the case then again edit your question to include cases where a key appears multiple times in your ample input/output and additionally explain how you want the handled.